# How to "instantiate" an enviroment in the current one?

Tags: r

Suppose that the function `foo` returns its enviroment, like this:

```
foo <- function () {
  a <- 42
  b <- "a string"
  x <- FALSE
  environment()
}
```

...and that function `bar` invokes `foo` like this:

```
bar <- function () {
  a <- 0
  z <- pi

  cat("before\n")
  print(ls.str())

  INSTANTIATE(foo())

  cat("after\n")
  print(ls.str())
}
```

...where `INSTANTIATE` is a *placeholder* for an as-yet undefined function (or construct).

The hypothetical expression `INSTANTIATE(foo())` is intended as shorthand for the directive

> instantiate the environment returned by `foo()` in the current enviroment.

By "instantiate" I mean that all the variables mentioned in `foo()` get created (if necessary) in the current enviroment, and assigned to values they have in `foo()`.

This means that the desired output for `bar()` is the following:

```
> bar()
before
a :  num 0
z :  num 3.14
after
a :  num 42
b :  chr "a string"
x :  logi FALSE
z :  num 3.14
```

My question is, what should I replace the expression `INSTANTIATE(foo())` such that the output of `bar()` looks like I've shown above?

EDIT: Please assume that `foo` should remain unchanged.

EDIT: This implementation of `INSTANTIATE(foo())`, inspired by Gregor's comment (or, rather, my interpretation thereof), does not work:

```
bar <- function () {
  a <- 0
  z <- pi
  cat("before\n")
  print(ls.str())

  list2env(as.list(foo()))

  cat("after\n")
  print(ls.str())
}

> bar()
before
a :  num 0
z :  num 3.14
after
a :  num 0
z :  num 3.14
```

Comment: Have `foo` return a list and use `list2env`. Though I do think the "*if necessary*" part of "get created (if necessary)" will take special handling. In general, assignments will overwrite any existing assignments.

Comment: @Gregor: sorry, I should have made clear that `foo` should remain unchanged; I've edited my post to fix this.

Comment: You need to specify "envir" in `list2env` -- `list2env(as.list(foo()), environment())`

Comment: @alexis_laz: thanks for the cluebrick, and to Gregor for the original idea; it works very nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this

```
import_env <- function(env, to=parent.frame()) {
    vars <- ls(envir=env)
    for(v in vars) {
        assign(v, get(v, env),to)
    }
}
```

Tested with

```
foo <- function () {
  a <- 42
  b <- "a string"
  x <- FALSE
  environment()
}

bar <- function () {
  a <- 0
  z <- pi

  cat("before\n")
  print(ls.str())

  import_env(foo())

  cat("after\n")
  print(ls.str())
}

bar()
# before
# a :  num 0
# z :  num 3.14
# after
# a :  num 42
# b :  chr "a string"
# x :  logi FALSE
# z :  num 3.14
```

Basically we just iterate the environment and assign all the variables over. This should work for atomic types. Things get a bit trickier if you ever tried to copy over functions or formulas which hold on to the environment where they were created.

Comment: Thank you!  That's great.  I'm surprised that something like your `import_env` is not already built into R, since instantiating/importing environments is one of the most obvious things one may want to do with them.